# On a cauchy problem (differential equation system) .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

I am approaching the theory of these kind of problems but I am missing an example.

I am tasked to solve:

$$X'= \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 4  \\ 1 & 1   \\  \end{array} \right)X + \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1   \\ 1    \\  \end{array} \right)e^t  , \ \ \ X(0) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 2  \\ 1    \\  \end{array} \right)  $$

the general solution ,from my understanding, is:

$$X(t) = e^{At}X(0) + e^{At}\int_0^te^{-As}f(s) ds$$

I think $ e^{At } $ is equal to $X(t)X(0)^{-1}$ but how can I invert a column vector?

Moreover I am unsure what to substitute in $\int_0^te^{-As}f(s)ds$.

Could I have an example or a reference so I can then try my hand on this problem?

Comment: @Amzoti ,thanks a ton for the example, but in the updated example I do not understand how you calculate $e^{At}$, I solved the associated homogeneous equation and got eigenvalues 3 and 1/2 and then?

Comment: @Amzoti Yes, I followed the links you gave me and reached a solution. I will copy it on here for others after the 28th. Thanks again.